# New user registration spam

Tags: wordpress, spam

My website uses Wordpress and we use a plugin called profile builder for registering new users who can access some more pages than non-registered ones. We have e-mail confirmation feature and do not auto-generate passwords. Lately we are seeing a lot of spam user ids being created. They never access the site. I wanted to know what possible benefit they might be getting by registering on our site and if we should delete off such ids. Is there any way to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, comment spammers generally sign up for the sole purpose of posting comments that ostensibly contain generic comments about the post (such mundane remarks as "wow this is really interesting"), but the real purpose is for them to post links to their websites in the hope of boosting their search engine ranking. If they're registering but not returning it could be some bot that's trying to perform automatic registrations in the hope that it can go on to automatically post comment spam.

To prevent it from happening, you could try adding a Captcha to your registration process, if that plugin will allow it.

If you find yourself getting comment spam then there's always the askismet plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [stop spammers plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-spammer-registrations-plugin/). If you didn't like it then you can choose one of these, [Sabre](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sabre/), [Growmap](https://wordpress.org/plugins/growmap-anti-spambot-plugin/), [wangguard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wangguard/). :)